# Lotus Notes limit user's outgoing email quota

Tags: lotus-notes

We are using Domino 9 mail server and I want to restrict all users from sending huge amount of emails in short amount of time. For example when some users compromise their credentials and hacker uses their accounts to send huge amount of emails to certain mail domains. I've found settings to block certain users to send emails in Server Document Settings but is there a way just to limit sending quota of outgoing emails not to restrict all outgoing emails?

Comment: A lot of third party products can do this, Domino on its own can't... But you are lucky: Never heard about a hacker to be able to remote control Notes Client to send mass mails...

Comment: It was sent by iNotes webmail. Could you name one of those third party software?